# App always paused in debugger on Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, freeze

I just migrated to Xcode 4.2 after a little coding break.

When 'Run'ing my app, it seems always to pause straigt after it has been loaded in the simulator/device.
I can't do any interaction, it just hangs at

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

with thread 1.

I used google, but couldnt find the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a crash of unknown origin. Try adding the following symbolic breakpoints to help you get to the bottom of this:

```
[NSException raise]
objc_exception_throw
malloc_error_break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue sounds a bit different (mine happens after heavy use) but I've had a similar behavior in Xcode 4 where my app crashes and no information is displayed in the debugger (just says Paused).  It turns out that this can happen when the app is jettisoned for using too much memory.  You can find a LowMemory report to verify this.